# Reverse LinkList whilst preserving original nodes

Tags: java, list, linked-list

My teacher has assigned a program where I am to create a linked list of some random numbers. I am to create it from a list and then the second part of the assignment is to reverse it. The actual quote is

> Write a Java method called reverseLinkedList() that will generate a
>   reversed linked-list from the linked-list that you create in problem
>   1. Your method should accept a linked-list as an input and return another linked list that has the node references in the reversed
>   order. Please do not print the original list in reverse. The idea is
>   to manipulate the node references so that the nodes are preserved in
>   same in order as they were originally created.

The code I have generated so far looks like

```
import java.util.*;

public class progassignment2 
{ 
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    { 
        List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Random ran = new Random();
        int ranNum;
        for(int x = 0;x<5;x++)
        {
            ranNum =  ran.nextInt(500);
            myList.add(x,ranNum);
        }
        LinkedList<Integer> mylinklist = createLinkedList(myList);
        System.out.println(mylinklist);
        LinkedList<Integer> mylinklistrev = reverseLinkedList(mylinklist);
    } 

    public static LinkedList createLinkedList(List<Integer> integerList)
    {
        LinkedList<Integer> linkedlist = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        linkedlist.addAll(integerList);
        return linkedlist;
    }

    public static LinkedList reverseLinkedList(LinkedList inputList)
    {
        for(int y = 0;y < inputList.size();y++)
        {
            inputList.addLast(inputList.pollFirst());
        }
        return inputList;
    }
 }
```

However I don't think I'm doing the assignment correctly, or that I understand what he is asking of me and unfortunately won't answer any questions and just cites "Read the assignment". Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Given the low level detail (I.e. explicitly referring to nodes) in the question, I very much doubt you’re supposed to be using `java.util.LinkedList` but rather implementing your own linked list. Depending on whether it is singly or doubly linked would impact how you’d then create a reversed linked list from your original...

Comment: What is the linked-list you created in problem 1? Read the assignment carefully to understand it. Like @d.j.brown says, I don't think you're supposed to be using `java.util.LinkedList` but rather your own implementation of a linked-list that I assume you created in problem 1.

Comment: Yeah, you are probably correct, the assignment page does not indicate it :/

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
public static LinkedList reverseLinkedList(List<Integer> inputList) {
    LinkedList<Integer> reversedLinkedlist = new LinkedList<Integer>(inputList);
    Collections.reverse(reversedLinkedlist);
    return reversedLinkedlist;
}
```

Comment: We haven't gone over collections in the coursework so I'm not sure if he'll take it.

Comment: @RyanJohnTyler So the task is to mutate collections without using them?

Comment: He just wants us to reverse a reverse a LinkedList, but when he says `The idea is to manipulate the node references so that the nodes are preserved in same in order as they were originally created.` I'm not sure if he just wants me to reverse the pointers?

Comment: @RyanJohnTyler so what's wrong with the proposed solution? The initial list is preserved as it is. The new one is created with a reversed node order. The node references are manipulated with the help of `Collections`. Doesn't it work as expected?

Comment: We just haven't gone over collections just yet in the coursework and I don't think he'll take it. I'm more than willing to try though

Comment: @RyanJohnTyler But `LinkedList` is a part of collections framework. Tell him that it's impossible to deal with collections without dealing with collections.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, exercises on linked lists do not make use of any built-in Java collection (like ArrayList, LinkedList, etc), but are instead meant to make you build your own collection type.

Your teacher probably wants you to build a very basic element, which would then become the building block of your own collection type: imagine an object where you can store a value and a reference to the following value in the list. In code:

```
class Node {
    private int value;
    private Node next;

    public Node(int value){
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue(){
        return value;
    }

    public Node getNext(){
        return next;
    }

    public void setNext(Node next){
        this.next = next;
    }
}
```

Each element points to the next one, and the end of the list is marked by the last node's next element being `null`.

By using objects like this, you'll be able to define your own linked list, without using any pre-defined Collection offered by Java.

You've surely heard about the `stack` data structure: by reading all the elements in your linked list and putting them inside a stack, once the list will be over, you're going to fetch the elements inside the stack; creating a linked list in the order of the elements pulled from the stack will solve your problem of inverting the linked list.

Answer (score 0):

> The idea is to manipulate the node references so that the nodes are
>   preserved in same in order as they were originally created.

You should create your own LinkedList. You are not allowed to use common ways of reversing like using recursion, stack ,modifications or any collections interface methods.

here is the [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-reverse-linked-list-using-stack/) includes `LinkedList` reversing ways and solution:

```
class LinkedList {
    Node head; // head of list
    /* Linked list Node */

    class Node {
        int data;
        Node next;

        Node(int d) {
            data = d;
            next = null;
        }
    }

    /* Function to print reverse of linked list */
    void printReverse(Node head) {
        if (head == null)
            return;
        // print list of head node
        printReverse(head.next);

        // After everything else is printed
        System.out.print(head.data + " ");
    }

    /* Inserts a new Node at front of the list. */
    public void push(int new_data) {
        Node new_node = new Node(new_data);

        new_node.next = head;

        head = new_node;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        LinkedList llist = new LinkedList();
        llist.push(4);
        llist.push(3);
        llist.push(2);
        llist.push(1);

        llist.printReverse(llist.head);
    }
}
```